# xcode - no option to add other c flags

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, openframeworks

I am working on a project for iOS using openFrameworks (C++) and Pure Data. I need to add C flags to the xcode project in order to compile. When I search the build settings for the other c flags option it does not exist. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Select the target, then Build Settings > Other C Flags. Be sure to select "All" rather than "Basic" at the top.

Comment: Option doesn't exist. I'm using xcode 4.5.2, osx 10.7.5, and the apple llvm compiler 4.1. There's an option for other c++ flags, but not c flags.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I was searching under basic instead of all.

Comment: thats why I have posted screenshot too...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click on Project -> Build Settings ->search **Other C Flags**

[image]

Comment: In case this is helpful to anyone else: this is shown in the screenshot, but I had to explicitly select "All" instead of "Basic" from within the Build Settings menu.

Comment: @RobertHickman: Thank you for the valuable comment. The screenshot is updated. The selected areas are marked with red.